# How to create id of input box of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have this form.

```
<table><tr><td>
<FORM>
<label> ID  </label></td>
<td>
<input type=text id="inputp1_id" size=24 class="text"> 
</td></tr>
<tr><td> 
   <label>Type</label></td><td><select id="inputp1_type" name="inputp1_type"><option value="text">Text</option><option value="integer">Integer</option><option value="float">Float</option><option value="list_values">List of values</option>
 <option value="range">Range</option><option value="selection_collapsed">Selection (collapsed)</option><option value="selection_expanded">Selection (expanded)</option><option value="subimage">Subimage selection</option>
<option value="polygon">Polygon selection</option><option value="horizontal_separator">Horizontal separator</option></select>
 </td></tr>
<tr><td> <label > Description</label></td> <td><input type=text id="inputpi_description" size=24 class="text"> </td><!--style=" width:300px; height:20px;"-->
</tr>
  <tr><td>      <label>Value</label></td><td> <input type="text" name="inputp1_value" id="inputp1_value" class="text" size=24></td></tr>
   <tr><td> <label > Info (help)</label></td><td>
    <input type=text id="input1_value" size=24 class="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label > Visible?</label></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="inputp1_visible" id="inputp1_visible"></td></tr></table>
        <!--</form>--></div>
```

But (it's possible?) can create the id's input box?
Because the variable these are "numbered".
For example the first id in the form is inputp1_id but the number i want use how variable.
It's possible create the id with the Javascript o Jquery?

```
l=3
Id='inputp' +l+'_id'
```

After this create the input text has the `id=inputp3_id`

Comment: ??? never it use y look at example....

Comment: l=3
Id='inputp' +l+'_id'
iT'S CORRECT??

Comment: guggelygock fragglerock 4/0*2=999

Comment: Adeneo What this is? guggelygock fragglerock 4/0*2=999

Comment: Hi Mirko, your question is not easy to understand. So he meaned it a bit ironic :-) But of course, it is simple to add the id attribute to any dom element via javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately I always use translate.google.it and i don't have the friend of America o London.
But it's possible that add the id attribute using the variable.
l=3 Id='inputp' +l+'_id' after id =inputp3_id
After the my input box is <input type=text id='inputp' +l+'_id' size=24 class="text"> but i don't look this example

Comment: Yes, it's obvious :-) and you are not the only man who uses the translator. Yes it's possible to create these elements dynamically. And much easier with jQuery than with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example on how to generate html contents dynamically with jquery and javascript. Both methods, although they look similar, give a bit different results: `jquery` generates one additional `<tbody>` tag, while `javascript` inserts the new rows directly to `<table>`. I recommend you to inspect the result in the Firefox's `DOM Inspector` by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. IT's very handy and effective tool. And here is the algorythm:

```js
var i=0; // this is simple counter

function generate_row_dynamically_in_jquery() {
    i++;
    var new_row = $('<tr/>');
    var new_cell1 = $('<td>ID <input type="text" name="inputp'+i+'_id" id="inputp'+i+'_id" size="24" class="text"/></td>');
    var new_cell2 = $('<td>Visible? <input type="checkbox" name="inputp'+i+'_visible" id="inputp'+i+'_visible"> </td>');
    new_row.append(new_cell1).append(new_cell2);
    $('#table1').append(new_row);
}

function generate_row_dynamically_in_javascript() {
    i++;
    var new_row = document.createElement('tr');
    var new_cell1 = document.createElement('td');
    new_cell1.innerHTML = 'ID <input type="text" name="inputp'+i+'_id" id="inputp'+i+'_id" size="24" class="text"/>';
    var new_cell2 = document.createElement('td');
    new_cell2.innerHTML = ' Visible? <input type="checkbox" name="inputp'+i+'_visible" id="inputp'+i+'_visible">';
    new_row.appendChild(new_cell1);
    new_row.appendChild(new_cell2);
    document.getElementById('table1').appendChild(new_row);
}
```

& @[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V2RLs/)

Comment: Thank you in italian is Grazie

Comment: Grazie Mirko :-) I simplified the jsfiddle again - now it is more obvious - and also there is one example in javascript, how to insert new rows at the beginning of the table. It's here: http://jsfiddle.net/V2RLs/2/ - Have a good time, Mirko!